# Writing difference between set of lines in two files in shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a diff of two files into one output file. ie) Contents of file1 but not in content of file2.

```
ex: cat file1
sam
robson
guugb


cat file2
sam
michg
Jay
```

For the above, I want of contents of file1, which is not in file2 has to be written to file2 itself. SO the final output will be:

```
cat file2
sam
michg
Jay
robson
guugb
```

Can anyone help in this.

Comment: This is BashFAQ #36: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that ordering will be lost:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u >combined && mv combined file2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `join`:**

```
join -a2 --nocheck-order file1 file2 > tmp && mv tmp file2
```

**Using `awk`:**

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {names[$1]++; next}
  ($1 in names) {delete names[$1]}
  END {for(name in names) print name >> "file2"}
' file1 file2
```

- Read the names from file1 into an array
- If the name is present in file2 delete it from array
- In the `END` block, iterate over our array and append the names to file2.

Comment: purporse of NR==FNR is??

Comment: It's an awk idiom that allows you to read or process first file completely.

Comment: in which instance the above command check for the names in file2? From your explanation, second stmt is doing, but I could not understand. Can you pls explain?

Comment: Names is the array. $1 in names checks the existence. If it present we clear the array entry